# Strange loss of collection items in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am experiencing a strange situation with my MVC code. I already read all I could on Internet the whole last week but no clue. Finally today I found the problem, but not the solution.

#### Scenario

I have a View that must show dynamically different dropdownlists. When the user selects an item from a dropdownlist, an action in the Controller is called asynchronically to check the rules for showing or hidding another dropdownlist in the View.

#### Problem summary

It seems that calling a method not involved with the model is affecting the model when sent back to the controller. With the method commented the model is posted back filled with the original data, when the code is active the collections are sent back empty.

#### Code

The model given to the View is:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyDropDownList> Ddls { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

The dropdownlists are defined like this:

```
public class MyDropDownList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

When 1st time the default Action is called the View is rendered flawlessly meaning that the model was filled with the proper data, and the small logic in the View with Razor worked too. Here the Action in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult showFirstView()
{
    List<string> selected = GetSelectedIds();
    var model = new MyViewModel('parameters');

    var hiddenIds = new List<string>();
    ApplyRules(GetRulesFromDatabase(), selected, hiddenIds);
    ViewBag.HiddenIds = hiddenIds;

    return View(model);
 }
```

Some explanations:

"GetSelectedIds" is a function to go through the collection of ddls and get the ids of all the SelectedValues, if any. The collection of ids is given later to the "ApplyRules" method.

The View is going to render any ddl if its Id is not in the ViewBag.HiddenIds collection. With the rules hardcoded it worked nicely.

Now, the View renders a PartialView in order to refresh that DIV element anytime the AJAX is called, that is when a ddl changes selection. Here the main View:

```
/*The main View*/
@model MyViewModel
...
<div class="row">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("refreshByAJAX", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Get", OnSuccess = "postAjaxOperations()" },this.Model))
    {    
        <div id="divToUpdate">
            @Html.Partial("_myPartialView", Model)
        </div>
     }

</div>
...
```

*(The protocol was supposed to be POST but I could only make it work with GET)*

Here the partial View:

```
/*The partial View*/
@model MyViewModel
...
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Ddls.Count; i++)
    {
       if (!ViewBag.HiddenIds.Contains(Model.Ddls[i].Id))
       { 
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Ddls[i].Items, "Value", "Text", Model.Ddls[i].SelectedValue), new { @class = "some-classes"})
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].Id)
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].Name)
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue)
        }
     }
</div>
...
<input type="submit" value="Ajax call" id="trigger" class="hidden" />
```

Comments: The only way I could post succesfully the full model back when the ddl changes selection is through a hidden input "submit", which is at the end of the partial. The ddl "onchange" jquery triggers the "click". Another important thing is the HiddenFor helpers. Without them the Binder is unable to persist the data in the model back to the controller, but notice that if the IF is not true, they are not created and the Ddl is going to be lost from the collection anyways.

#### First problem, solved

When an item was selected in a ddl, an Action in the controller is called asynchronically (Ajax.BeginForm) to refresh the dropdownlists. But it was sending the model totally empty (or some collections within the model empty) (null). It was quite tricky, but I got the Ajax call to send the entire model back to the Action properly.

The rules to show/hide the other dropdownlists in the View were hardcoded for simplicity and the View was refreshing whith the right ddls correctly. Here the Action called with Ajax:

```
/* Method called by AJAX */
public PartialViewResult refreshByAJAX(MyViewModel model)
{
    List<string> selected = GetSelectedIds(model);
    model = new MyViewModel('params');

    var hiddenIds = new List<string>();
    ApplyRules(GetRulesFromDatabase(), selected, hiddenIds);
    ViewBag.HiddenIds = hiddenIds;

    return PartialView("_myPartialView", model);
}
```

#### Current problem

Now I replaced the harcoded logic for the real one, taken the rules from the database. With this the View is filled correctly with the right dropdownlists, but when I select an item, the Ajax call to the Action is sending the model with all the Ddls collection EMPTY again !!

Likely you will be quick to say that obviously the logic to hide/show the dropdowns is wrong. And probably it is, since if I comment it, the problem is solved. But what does it do? Just to add the string Id to a collection in the ViewBag. Here the fateful 'ApplyRules' method:

```
/* Method in the controller (not Action)*/
private void ApplyRules(List<Rule> rules, List<string> selected, List<string> hiddenIds)
{
    foreach (var rule in rules)
    {
        if (rule.Action == "show")
        {
            if (!selected.Contains(rule.RequiredDdlId))
            {
                 hiddenIds.Add(rule.AffectedDdlId);
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Here the Rule class, although not relevant:

```
public class Rule 
{
    public string Action { get; set; }  // "Hide" or "Show"
    public string AffectedDdlId { get; set; }
    public string RequiredDdlId { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that the 'ApplyRules' method is not touching the model. But if I comment it, then the model is given back to controller with all the Ddls in the collection. If it is active, the Ddls collection is posted empty (null).

The test case is with 2 ddls. The main ddl is always visible. The second ddl is by default hidden with the 1st run of "ApplyRules" in the default Action and must be shown only when a specific item is selected in the main ddl. Then the AJAX method is called, the "ApplyRules" method should remove it from the ViewBag.HiddenIds, but this fail before since the collection comes empty. If the "ApplyRules" method is commented, only the main ddl is posted back within the collection, which is correct (because the HiddenFor helpers are not generated if the IF is false, and the Binder loses it). But if "ApplyRules" method is activated, both are removed from the collection.
Comments: The main dropdownlist is always visible. There is not rule to set it hidden, and it is visible even after the postback. With breakpoints everywhere I debugged and checked that all the values are as supposed all the timeline. But even this main Ddl is removed from the collection if the "ApplyRules" is active.

Also, the first approach was to use a field in the "myDropDownList" class itself to set it "visible" or "hidden". Blaming on that, I changed to use the ViewBag and not to touch the model, with the same failed result.

Thank you in advance for any theory. I will be glad to add extra info if it helps or answer questions.

Comment: Um, wall of code dude!

Comment: Your question is very detailed, but you may want to see if you can narrow down the problem a little more, because your question is very long.  Also, what's `GetRulesFromDatabase()` doing?

Comment: You have an `if` statement inside a `for` loop. If it does not evaluate to `true` then you will get non sequential indexers which will no bind to a collection (indexers must start at zero and e consecutive) unless you add a `<input name="Ddls.Index" value="@i" />` And `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue)` is a bit pointless. You already have a dropdownlist for the same property so its just ignored.

Comment: Just curious, Stephen .. your answer is within a comment thus it cannot be rated or marked as the solution. Anyways, than you very much. BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly! Stephen Muecke was absolutely right. Problem solved.

Efectively, the collection of Ddls was serialized starting from index 1. (The "hide" rule was affecting the 1st element in the collection). Following are the ids generated for the HiddenFor attributes:

```
 <input id="Ddls_1__Id" name="Ddls[1].Id" value=... type="hidden">
 <input id="Ddls_1__Name" name="Ddls[1].Name" value="..." type="hidden">
```

So I made it to start from zero index, and the collection was bound again and given to the controller in the AJAX call.

To test it, I changed the show/hide logic in the PartialView. Instead creating the dropdownlists (and its HiddenFor helpers) only if the rule was "show", I changed it to create all the dropdownlists always, but making them invisible appending the class "hidden" in the htmlAttributes.

```
/*The adjusted partial View*/
 @model MyViewModel
 ...
 <div>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Ddls.Count; i++)
     {
        string hiddenClass = "";
        // The string hiddenClass will be "hidden" only for the Ddls marked as hidden from the ApplyRules method.
        if (ViewBag.HiddenIds.Contains(Model.Categories[i].Id))
        {
            hiddenClass = "hidden";   
        }
        // The objects are created even if are hidden
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Ddls[i].Items, "Value", "Text", Model.Ddls[i].SelectedValue), new { @class = "some-classes " + hiddenClass})
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].Name)
      }
 </div>
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="Ajax call" id="trigger" class="hidden" />
```

Thanks Stephen for your great help.

Comment: Generating a hidden dropdown list is unnecessary and not good performance. You could just generate a hidden input instead of a dropdown - `if(...) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue) } else { @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ddls[i].SelectedValue, ...) } @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Ddls[i].Id) ...`

Comment: Nice extra hint to optimize the code, @StephenMuecke. (I still cannot rate your useful comments).